# material design lite not working in my website

Tags: html, css, material-design, material-design-lite

i tried making an html template with google material design lite and added and header which is working fine but as i am adding anything below it, it is just moving to the top . See the code for help :

```css
.demo-layout-transparent {
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1456428199391-a3b1cb5e93ab?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=db130336e8134fc3f734dbc4318f5c5e') center / cover;
  font-family: 'League Spartan';
}

.demo-layout-transparent .mdl-layout__header,
.demo-layout-transparent .mdl-layout__drawer-button {
  color: white;
}

.mdl-layout-title {
    font-family: 'League Spartan';
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-top: 1em;
}

.subtitle {
    font-family: "League Spartan";
    font-size: 4em;
    color: floralwhite;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2em;
}

.subtitle span{
    color: deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

    
    
<body>
    <div class="home">
 <div class="demo-layout-transparent mdl-layout mdl-js-layout" id="header">
     <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--transparent">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <!-- Title -->
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">DesignAmbition</span>
      <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <!-- Navigation -->
      <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Home</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">About</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Portfolio</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
     <h1 class="subtitle">We Create <span>DESIGNS</span> <br/> And People Just <br/>.......... <br/> <span>ADMIRE</span> </h1>
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer mdl-layout--small-screen-only">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Design <br/> Ambition`</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Home</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">About</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Portfolio</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
  </main>
     
     </div>
    </div>
    
    
<div class="mdl-layout__content">
        <h1> ABOUT </h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contents should be in `<div class="page-content">`.
**Edit:** Header is transparent in your page. I removed `--transparent` from Header class to gain color for it. CSS also have been updated by changing the size of your margin-top to 5px (3em was too large for header). Font size is also changed to 2em from 3em for Header title. Also removed `<div class="home">` because there is no use of it.

```css
.demo-layout-transparent {
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1456428199391-a3b1cb5e93ab?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=db130336e8134fc3f734dbc4318f5c5e') center / cover;
  font-family: 'League Spartan';
}

.demo-layout-transparent .mdl-layout__header,
.demo-layout-transparent .mdl-layout__drawer-button {
  color: white;
}

.mdl-layout-title {
    font-family: 'League Spartan';
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.subtitle {

    font-size: 4em;
    color: floralwhite;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2em;
}

.subtitle span{
    color: deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="demo-layout-transparent mdl-layout mdl-js-layout" id="header">
      <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
          <!-- Title -->
          <span class="mdl-layout-title">Design Ambition</span>
          <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
          <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
          <!-- Navigation -->
          <nav class="mdl-navigation">
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Home</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">About</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Portfolio</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Contact</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>

      <div class="mdl-layout__drawer mdl-layout--small-screen-only">

        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Design <br/> Ambition`</span>
        <nav class="mdl-navigation">
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Home</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">About</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Portfolio</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Contact</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <div class="page-content">
          <!-- contents starts here -->

          <h1 class="subtitle">We Create <span>DESIGNS</span> <br/> And People Just <br/>.......... <br/> <span>ADMIRE</span> </h1>
          <h1>About</h1>

          <!-- contents ends here -->
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your answer seems correct but what if i want to give the header a background and the first heading in the header and the second below the header i.e. where the background image ends.

Comment: Actually i am beginner in web design

Comment: Funny I do not see what the different to my answer 19h ago (beside of verbosity). @pulkit please explain in are update to your question what the goal is,

Comment: Thanks for your help. You are so close to what i wanted but i want to put the ABOUT section below the header section. So the About heading have to be placed below the background image  of the header and not on it.

Comment: @pulkit actually, i not getting the point. Could you make it clear?

Comment: Actually, i wanna make sections in my page like HOME,ABOUT,SERVICES, etc. You can check out this templates for understanding what i am trying to build. http://shapebootstrap.net/item/1524983-spirit8-free-bootstrap-html-template/live-demo                                                                                  http://bootstraptaste.com/demo/Ninestars/

Comment: @pulkit getmdl does not give any components for those type. Mdl is lite. So, you will have to do it manually. A little Google searches can find you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the goal is, but try to put your content into the main element.

```
<main class="mdl-layout__content">
  <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
</main>
```

Or into a additional header element.

Comment: Just try to run this in your browser and you will see that the h1 heading stating ABOUT moves to the top of the page

Comment: And if you put it into main it will not.

Comment: I also tried putting it in main but nothing changed

Comment: There are two h1  tags (.subtitel and ABOUT)   in your example.  Both seem to belong into main.